# AWS Kinesis Firehose to ElasticSearch Geo data mapping

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have Kinesis Firehose stream loading data into an Elasticsearch cluster.
This data has a latitude and a longitude field.
In Elasticsearch I want to visualize this data in a geographical map. But Elasticsearch only accepts the geo_point field type.

How can I map the latitude and longitude fields to a geo point field in Elasticsearch?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting up custom lambda function for your Kinesis Delivery Stream transforming the data into ES suitable format.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set up index with mapping to accept geo objects.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html

Outlined here.

And then you can feed in the long/lat in 1 of the 4 formats specified.